# Formatting in MS Access

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am trying to format a `Access` table fields to include all values as in the images below. However when I copy and paste from `excel` to the `Access` table, only significant figures appear in the table. The fields are currently of `Text` Datatype, I have tried `Number` Datatype but the values get rounded up. How do I correct this to accomplish this task? Is there a `SQL` query I can run to return the expected formatting?

**Currently if I copy and paste from excel to Access:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Perhaps If I leave the fields as `Text` Datatype, would the `Format()` method using the approach below sort it out:

```
SELECT Format(ExchangeRate, "#.######"), Format(ForeignGross, "#.##")  
FROM tab1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, set the *Format* property for those two fields, respectively:

```
0.000000
0.00
```

Never store amounts or quantities as text. Change Field `Data Type` to `Number` and use `Field Size: Double` and `Format: 0.000000` and `0.00` respectively.

Comment: I have changed the field property to `Number` and used `0.000000` in the format property. Is there a reason why Access keeps rounding off when I copy `Number` formatted column from excel and try pasting it on the access table?

Comment: There is no rounding off. It is pure formatting, which the copying doesn't carry over as it copies the values only.

Comment: in my case, If I chage the field to Number type and use `0.000000` and copy the value `1.278900` from excel and pasting it on access, the results in  `1.000000`. If I leave the field as a `Text` datatype and use `Format([ExchangeRate], "#,##0.000000")` in a query,  it sort of does the job. I would prefer the formatting to be done on the table but this is still not happening. Thx

Comment: _1.278900 from excel and pasting it on access, the results in 1.000000_. This will happen if the data type of the field in the table is integer. Use Double or Decimal.

Comment: Nice! I have used `Field Size: Double` and `Format: 0.000000` thank you!